# Change all previous siblings and previous cousins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the example below, I'm trying to get all `<li>`'s before (and including the current `<li>`) the `class="current"` to have a background colour of tomato.

So in this example: 1,2,3,4 and 5 would have the background colour tomato.

And I need it to update if the `<li>` that `class="current"` is on changes.

```
<div id="container">

  <div class="menu-1">

    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="menu-2">

    <ul>
      <li>4</li>
      <li class="current">5</li>
      <li>6</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="menu-3">

    <ul>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
    </ul>

 </div>

</div>
```

I can do it for all previous siblings (but not cousins) with

```
#container .current ~ li {
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

Or using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.current').prevAll('li').css('background','tomato');
});
```

But I'm really struggling to get it to work for previous cousins.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/eb0vLswu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.current').prevAll('li').andSelf().css('background','tomato');
    $('.current').closest('div').prevAll('div').find('li').css('background','tomato');
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgno2c1d/) demonstrating it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list-items li").each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('current')) {
      $(this).prevAll("li").addClass('disable');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
li:hover,
.current {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
}
.disable {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list-items">
  <li>List item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
  <li class="current">Current item</li>
  <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

**Edit:** To include the current li use: `$(this).prevAll("li").andSelf().addClass('disable');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.current').prevAll('li').andSelf().css('background','tomato');
    $('.current').parent().parent().prevAll('div').find('li').css('background','tomato');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <div class="menu-1">

    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="menu-2">

    <ul>
      <li>4</li>
      <li class="current">5</li>
      <li>6</li>
    </ul>

  </div>

  <div class="menu-3">

    <ul>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
    </ul>

 </div>

</div>
```